# I get this error There is a problemm parsing the package in Android

Tags: android

I am geting this error when I try to download the file from any website only, when I compile from Eclipse it works, when I upload in dropbox and download from dropbox also it works. It sounds very strange and I can't get to know why when I try to download the apk file from a website shows me the error "I get this error There is a problem parsing the package"

I have started this project with api level 10 and in manifest file I have changed it minSdkVersion="7" I thought maybe problem is here something but still the same either I put it 10 or 7 or 8 its still getting the same error when I try to download from any site which I uploaded.

Thanx

Comment: Is it possible that you have the application installed with a different signature on your device? What are you using to host the file on the website? If you are hosting on iis you might have to add the apk mime type in your iis settings.

Comment: http://www.filejumbo.com/Download/490CEE54CE996C39 here i have the file and simply i use upload button to upload it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run a clean?

Eclipse menus -> Project -> clean

Android devel tools are still somewhat buggy.